# System.IO.IOException при приеме сообщений в tcp чате

Tags: c#, wpf, tcp

Пытаюсь создать tcp-чат в wpf. Возникла проблема при получении сообщений (метод ниже). Проверив в отладке заметил, что цикл выполняется несколько раз, но в определенный момент выдает: 
System.IO.IOException: "Не удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения: Операция блокирования прервана вызовом WSACancelBlockingCall."

Уверен, что проблема не на стороне сервера, т.к. точно такой же клиентский код исправно работает в консоли. Проблема появилась именно в wpf.
Как исправить?

```
    public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[64]; // строка с ошибкой
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                string message = builder.ToString();
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.tb_messages.Text += message));
            }
            catch
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.tb_messages.Text = "Соединение было прервано"));
                Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: WPF тут явно ни причем. Программу надо разделять на слои. Работу с сервером нужно выделять в отдельный слой (класс) и писать его применяя тестирование, а когда он будет готов, вот тогда начинать работу над проектом WPF, т.е. писать UI к этому классу. Так отделяют мух от котлет, т.е. правильная работа с сервером это одна задача, а взаимодействие с пользователем - совсем другая отдельная задача.

Comment: @Bulson Не совсем понимаю, как занесение метода в класс поспособствует его работоспособности? О каком тестировании идет речь? Как правильно такое осуществить?

Comment: Правильный принцип работы избавляет от путаницы и неверных предположений в случае возникновения ошибок. `Проблема появилась именно в wpf.` - это неверное предположение. Если бы вы начинали написание с проекта библиотеки DLL с классом(и) по взаимодействию с сервером, то тогда точно могли бы локализовать причину ошибки, а она очевидно ни как не связана с WPF. Под тестированием я подразумевал написание юнит-тестов.